# direction property with border-radius issue with IE9

Tags: css

```
direction: rtl;
font-size: large;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 0px;
border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 0px;
```

I've noticed IE9 changes the way it reads border radius values, in the case above it reads the top left as top right and the styled div would render in the other direction unlike chrome and moz!

any ideas?

Comment: You can remove the `-moz-` and `-webkit-` lines, both browsers support the proper format now. Maybe if you do that, you might see if all browsers have this behaviour or if it really is just IE.

Comment: could you reproduce the problem in a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Apparently IE9 is taking "CSS direction property" a little too literally...

Comment: here's a tinkerbin link of the problem:[link](http://tinkerbin.com/Tk8bvjm8)

Comment: by the way, I've worked around this problem by wrapping the arabic text inside a p tag and assigning the rtl direction property to the p tag and the problem is all gone, but still it is an issue and I need to know if it is a bug or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you just define `top-right-border-radius`and so on. And don't remove the `-moz-` because a lot of Firefox users don't upgrade when they should.

Or you can use [IE conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            property: value;
        </style>
        <!--[if IE]>
            <style>
                ie-only-property: value;
            </style>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        Page text here
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug in IE9 that occurs when the element has `direction: rtl;` (either directly on the element with `border-radius` or inherited from a parent of that element).

the solution is to apply `direction: ltr;` on the element.